# Converting the past into reported speech

Tags: passive-voice, ambiguity, reported-speech, past-vs-past-perfect

My grammar book says that if somebody says to me something and he uses *the past tense*, I can report his speech using either *the past* or *past perfect*. (In the first case I don't change the tense at all.)

For me it yields ambiguity. For example I hear this:

> "John said that he **was** not enjoying his job very much."

My understanding is that John could have said two different things. And I'm not sure whether John is still working there or not.

> John: "I **am** not enjoying my job very much.
>
> John: "I **was** not enjoying my job very much.

Do native speakers always rely on the context in these situations to avoid ambiguity? Or there is something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking you would backshift thus:

> **John:** “I **am not enjoying** my job very much.” → John said he **was not enjoying** his job very much.
>
> **John:** “I **was not enjoying** my job very much.” → John said he **had not been enjoying** his job very much.

This is the use you should follow, particularly in formal writing, to avoid ambiguity.

As you say, however, context will usually inform you what is meant; the second example, for instance, probably occurs in a context where John is known to have been talking about his prior experience, not his current state. Consequently, in non-formal writing and in speech the simple-past backshift is often employed where the past perfect is called for. This is not an ‘error’; it’s just an instance of what I call the *Tolerance Maxim*, that in speech (or in writing which emulates speech) “Whatever should be understood may be omitted”.

Comment: If John's statement is already in *Past Perfect* - John: "I **had been** enjoying my job before it **happened**." How would I *report* his speech? "John said he **had been** enjoying his job before it **had happened**." ? I cannot backshift *Past Perfect* any further.

Comment: @Graduate That's right. There's only one Reference Time in an utterance, there's no recursion. But note that there's also no ambiguity in your sentence: 'it' happening is a terminus ad quem.

Comment: No ambiguity because of the word `before`. Without it it could be a mess.

Comment: @Graduate Not a 'mess', just ambiguous outside an actual discourse--which is true of any utterance. Real sentences, unlike textbook conundrums, occur in discourse.